# Reuse of same layouts inside one layout using multiple includes - TabLayout + ViewPager + RecyclerView (multiple viewpagers in one View)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

I am using a Galaxy Tab E SM-T560. I am a 3 years android developer, just working on internet-search-problem-solving. I have searched for View implementations like inflation and *getParent()* things, and none of them worked.

In my case I have a layout for tablets, that has 2 includes of a Layout that has TabLayout plus ViewPager, and with this viewpager I use it with recyclerview

My code is not working at some point, I have made some copy paste to know why is not working, but didn't proceed for long searches.

Here is an image of only one working view inside this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZigU.png

Here is the code of the fragment that does all of this magic in the right of the drawer:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import br.com.adriankohls.volkmannbus2.R;
import br.com.adriankohls.volkmannbus2.fragmentstatepageadapters.horario.HorarioBlumenauPomerodeFragmentStatePageAdapter;
import br.com.adriankohls.volkmannbus2.fragmentstatepageadapters.horario.HorarioPomerodeBlumenauFragmentStatePageAdapter;
import br.com.adriankohls.volkmannbus2.utils.AppUtils;

public class HorarioFragment extends Fragment {

private boolean isToBlumenau;
private View rootView;

public static HorarioFragment newInstance(boolean isToBlumenau) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    HorarioFragment fragment = new HorarioFragment();
    fragment.isToBlumenau = isToBlumenau;
    bundle.putString(fragment.getTag(), AppUtils.getFragmentKey(fragment));
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

public HorarioFragment() {
    super();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView == null) {
        if (!AppUtils.isTablet()) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager_tablayout_horario, container, false);
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            TextView tvDestino = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDestino);
            ImageView imgInfo = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgInfo);
            if (isToBlumenau) {
                viewPager.setAdapter(new HorarioPomerodeBlumenauFragmentStatePageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getContext()));
                tvDestino.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rota_horario)[0]);
            } else {
                viewPager.setAdapter(new HorarioBlumenauPomerodeFragmentStatePageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), getContext()));
                tvDestino.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rota_horario)[1]);
            }

            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            AppUtils.tabLayoutRuleTablet(tabLayout);

            tvDestino.setOnClickListener(switchHorario());
            imgInfo.setOnClickListener(infoHorario());
        } else {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horario_tablet, container, false);

            rootView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setUpPomerodeBlumenau();
                    setUpBlumenauPomerode();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    return rootView;
}

private void setUpPomerodeBlumenau() {
    View view = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_horario_pombnu);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(
            new HorarioPomerodeBlumenauFragmentStatePageAdapter(
                    getChildFragmentManager(),
                    getContext()));

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setUpBlumenauPomerode() {
    View view = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_horario_bnupom);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(
            new HorarioBlumenauPomerodeFragmentStatePageAdapter(
                    getChildFragmentManager(),
                    getContext()));

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

This is my layout horario_tablet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horario_pombnu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/pomerodeblumenau"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_viewpager_tablayout" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horario_bnupom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/blumenaupomerode"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_viewpager_tablayout" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this the fragment_viewpager_tablayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

RecyclerView is working fine, for phones all of the views are fine, just on this case, the second layout inside the horario_tablet.xml show the tabs but won't show the fragments for each tab on tablayout of the second layout (@+id/layout_horario_bnupom), even the code is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer
I have replaced all the  tags for the hardcoded XML inclusion before in horario_tablet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horario_pombnu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/pomerodeblumenau"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar_pombnu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs_pombnu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_pombnu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horario_bnupom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/blumenaupomerode"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar_bnupom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs_bnupom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_bnupom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***OK, but why did you this?***

It's simple: for some reason Android Framework was using the first instance of the viewpager (first viewpager on layout) and not recreating another.

***SO??????***

So the solution was to give specific ids for each viewpager/tablayout

***:)***

**EDIT:**
**OK, but how did you reach that conclusion? (Framework, instance, bla bla bla?)**

Found the explanation here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/cKdvKyneHYY